# wxpython frame run from ArcMap loses focus almost immediately after it's shown

Tags: arcmap, python-addin, gui, wxpython

I'm trying to prepare a Python add-in using "Python Add-In Wizard". I want my add-in to perform some geoprocessing but first it should take data from a user and there's already a problem. I'm displaying a wxpython GUI and it loses focus and hides behind the arcmap window almost immediately after it's shown. I have no idea how to debug it and what could cause the problem. I decided to go this way after getting hands on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73900/how-to-create-parameter-windows-for-custom-geoprocessing-tools) example.

My code is here:

**addin.py**

```py
from dialogs.import_dialog import ImportDialog

class ImportButton(object):
    """Runs the import function."""
    dlg = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False

    def onClick(self):
        if self.dlg is None:
            self.dlg = ImportDialog()
        else:
            self.dlg.Show()
```

**import_dialog.py**

```py
class ImportDialog(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wxStyle = wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "some msg", style=wxStyle, size=(350, 200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.path_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"some msg", pos=(8, 8))
        self.input_path = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, value="", pos=(8, 36), size=(330, 21))

        self.path_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY,
                                        u"some msg",
                                        pos=(8, 65))

        self.group_layers = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, pos=(8, 93), size=(330, 21))

        self.ok_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="OK", pos=(8, 130))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)

        self.Center()
        self.Show(True)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Show(False)
```

Comment: You might be able to use [`wx.Window.Reparent()`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#Reparent) to make the dialog a child window of ArcMap, but never having tried it I couldn't say for sure. Also see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15863617/386205 Basically you need to import wx before the ArcMap event loop starts by implementing an extension in your add-in.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to prevent the losing focus on your dialog? I looked into the Reparenting but am unsure of how to get the ArcMap Window to Reparent with.

Comment: @user30558 Unfortunately not, I'm not sure how one could reparent the arcmap window since it's not wx compatible.